# Show extra form input fields when an html select option is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I want a selection of text fields to become visible when a  option is selected (and to hide others) unfortunately my attempts at JavaScript are terrible.

aaa selected xxx, yyy visible
bbb selected xxx, zzz visible
ccc selected yyy, zzz visible

### CSS Code:

```
.aaa, .bbb, .ccc {
    display:none;
}
```

### HTML Code:

```
<select  onchange="showExtra(this)">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
  <option value="bbb">BBB</option>
  <option value="ccc">CCC</option>
</select>

<div class="aaa bbb">
  <input name="xxx" type="text" />
</div>
 <div class="aaa ccc">
  <input name="yyy" type="text" />
</div>
  <div class="bbb ccc">
<input name="zzz" type="text" />
</div>
```

### JavaScript Code:

```
function showExtra(option)
{
   var divClass = option.value;
   $(divClass:not).hide();
   $divClass.slideDown('medium');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have reformatted a few things:

html:

```
<select id="selector">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
  <option value="bbb">BBB</option>
  <option value="ccc">CCC</option>
</select>

<div class="aaa bbb op">
  <input name="xxx" type="text"  placeholder="xxx"/>
</div>
 <div class="aaa ccc op">
  <input name="yyy" type="text" placeholder="yyy"/>
</div>
  <div class="bbb ccc op">
<input name="zzz" type="text" placeholder="zzz"/>
</div>
```

gave the selector an id to trigger in the jQ function also gave each hidden option a common class to select all at once.

jq:

```
$('#selector').on('change',function()
{
   var divClass = $(this).val();
   $(".op").hide();
   $("."+divClass).slideDown('medium');
});
```

binds onChange to selector, gets current value, hides all options, shows the related ones
http://jsfiddle.net/66rN8/1/

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z4SDB/)

```
var showExtra = function(option)
{
   var divClass = option.value;
   $("div:not(." + divClass + ")").hide();
   $("." + divClass).slideDown('medium');
}
```

It's worth noticing , that you should consider also adding `div:not` otherwise you risk with hiding your select, if that is not par of the plan.

Remember that : selecting by class name requires `.` in `.className` and so on, read about selectors :)

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could toggle the display property of the styles.

```
function showExtra(option)
{
   var divClass = option.value;
   $('.' + divClass).css({ display: 'inline' });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? way with jquery
http://jsfiddle.net/HxGQ6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').change(function () {
    var a=$(this).find("option:selected");
    var b=a.val();
    $(".aaa,.bbb,.ccc").hide();
    $("."+b).show();
});
```

});